# what does correlation $\rho$ means in surface SVI?

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, volatility-smile, volatility-surface

Why does everyone say $\rho$ is correlation in Surface SVI?

$w = \frac{\theta_t}{2}(1+\rho\psi(\theta_t)k + \sqrt{(\psi(\theta_t)k+\rho)^2+1-\rho^2})$, with $\rho \in [-1,1]$

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.00312.pdf) says it is proportional to the slope of smile at the ATM point.

[This paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2971502) says it is the correlation between the stock price
and its instantaneous volatility. What is the instantaneous volatility? I am confused because I am using surface SVI to model the implied volatility instead of stochastic volatility.

Comment: SVI can actually be derived as a limit of the Heston model. From that perspective you could say that $\rho$ is the correlation between the instantaneous vol and the spot. But in the context of IV interpolation I'd simply associate it with deviation from a perfectly symmetric smile as you can check yourself by plugging in $\rho = 0$ in the formula.